# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `type` of value `search` supplied to `Input`

Tags: reactjs, input, react-props

Getting failed prop type due to type="search" on input. 
Says:
"Failed prop type: Invalid prop `type` of value `search` supplied to `Input`, expected one of ["text","number","password","date","date-range","email","tel"]"

```
 <Input
   type="search"
   onChange={this.onSearchChange}
   iconSize={IconSize.xs}
   color="primary"
/>
```

The input with type="search" works as intended, but it keeps giving me console errors. Anyone knows why? And how to fix it?

Comment: which library are you using? Because that is not a default input tag. Anyway, that library only supports input type of "text","number","password","date","date-range","email","tel"

Comment: @kkesley Yes but then I lose the functionality that "search" gives me, which is clearing all text in the input field by pressing the X that appears when start typing.

Comment: @kkesley Also its our own component with custom props. Its still based on the default Input tag.

Comment: can you provide us the prop validation for that custom component?

Comment: @kkesley ahh ofc! The issue was in there. Wasnt me who wrote it and saw search was not one of the allowed ones. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Input />` is a custom component. From the comment, you said it's your own component. Check your prop validation as currently it only allows `["text","number","password","date","date-range","email","tel"]`.

You can add `"search"` in the validation.

Answer (score 0):

If going through the error message.
"Failed prop type: Invalid prop type of value search supplied to Input, expected one of ["text","number","password","date","date-range","email","tel"]

As in your code you have passed value "search" to type property of Input Component.
Basically type doesn't recognise  value "search" as it expect value to be "text", "number", "password", "date", "date-range", "email" or "tel".

Your Input component will be working fine cause of your some logic written in onSearchChange method.

To fix this error set the value of type which are specified in ["text","number","password","date","date-range","email","tel"].

For ex. if you're using only text for searching set it to "text", for number set it to "number" and so on.

Comment: But then I lose the functionality for search, which is to clean all text in the field by pressing the X that appears. Thats the reason why I set it to "search".

Comment: @stAMy which library are you using?